# what is the default value in reloptions that ran autovacuum is running

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have checked table in Postgres server.

```
SELECT reloptions
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'log_xxx_table';
```

I guessed that return data is `"autovacuum_enabled = true"` but return data is `null`.

This table have vacuum log ran autovacuum.

default reloptions is null but autovacuum_enabled = true?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `reloptions` is null, what means that configurable options are set to their default values. The default value of `autovacuum_enabled` is `true`. You can set it like in the example:

```
create table a_table(id int)
with (autovacuum_enabled = false);

select relname, reloptions
from pg_class
where relname = 'a_table';

 relname |         reloptions         
---------+----------------------------
 a_table | {autovacuum_enabled=false}
(1 row)
```