# PostgreSQL autovacuum Statistic Level For Table Column

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

We can list tables' s custom options why checking pg_class' s reloptions columns. For example; [like this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569078/what-is-the-default-value-in-reloptions-that-ran-autovacuum-is-running)

```
select relname, reloptions
from pg_class
where relname = 'a_table';
```

Yet, I couldn' t find anything in official documents and on the internet to list custom statistic settings for columns after altering them like this:

```
ALTER TABLE name ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET STATISTICS integer;
```

How can we list those settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics target is not a property of the table, but a property of the column. Therefore, you will find it in the metadata table of columns, which is `pg_attribute`. The column in question is `attstattarget`. Other per-column settings can be found in `attoptions`.